# Is there a standard abbreviation for "independent, uniformly distributed"?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, soft-question, terminology

The abbreviation for "independent, identically distributed" is "IID".

Is there a standard abbreviation for the narrower concept "independent, uniformly distributed"?

"IUD" is the obvious choice, but I don't think this abbreviation is common, so even in a mathematical text, readers might have to momentarily think, "oh, not the birth control method, i.e. intrauterine device".  "UID" is another option, but the phrase "uniform, independently distributed" doesn't map as naturally to the broader "independent, identically distributed".

(Seems like this might be a duplicate, but I couldn't find an earlier version.)

Comment: Is there even a standard abbreviation for i.i.d. Gaussians (IGD? IND?) which are perhaps more common in applications than IUD?

Comment: Good point.  Seems like it would be useful to have such an abbreviation, but I agree, @antkam, I've never seen it.  "GID" and "NID" would be easy to say, even though they're backwards.

Comment: Or French-style: Distribution Indépendante Gaussienne: "DIG"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen an abbreviation for this in the literature.

If you mean the continuous uniform distribution, you can of course write something like "iid $U(0,1)$", or "independent $U(a_n, b_n)$" if they don't all have the same distribution.  Otherwise I would just write "independent uniform".

Comment: Ah, right, good idea for the continuous case.  The particular case I'm thinking about concerns pseudorandom number generators, where a uniform distribution over multiples of $1/2^{32}$ in $(0,1)$  is used to represent a continuous uniform distribution over $(0,1)$.  It would be useful to have a term for both.  Maybe I'll just define it as I see fit.  If there's no tradition, I'm reluctant to use "IUD", for the reasons I gave.